# prevent ScrollViewer to swallow MouseWheelEvent (Update: DevExpress LayoutControl is the reason)

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, devexpress

I have an UserControl that contains a ScrollViewer which contains a Canvas.
I have custom zoom logic, but if the ScrollViewer can scroll it swallows the mousewheel event completly. When the bottom is reached zooming works without problem.

```
    private void CanvasOverlayControl_PreviewMouseWheel(object sender, MouseWheelEventArgs e) {
        if(Keyboard.IsKeyDown(Key.LeftCtrl) || Keyboard.IsKeyDown(Key.RightCtrl)) {
            if(e.Delta > 0) {
                // Wheel up
                Zoom *= 1.15f;
            } else if(e.Delta < 0) {
                // Wheel down
                Zoom *= 0.85f;
            }
        }
    }
```

this line is in the constructor (code behind)

```
        PreviewMouseWheel += CanvasOverlayControl_PreviewMouseWheel;
```

How can I supress that behaviour?

**Edit:**

I found out DevExpress LayoutControl is causing this because it handles the scrolling of content. Is there any way to disable this?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

Lets start with the basics... ensure that the Canvas is actually getting any mouse events. It needs some background to allow hit testing

```
<Canvas Background="Transparent"
```

For me, the `PreviewMouseWheel` of a canvas is hit and I can disable scrolling of the parent by setting `e.Handled = true;`.

Edit: the sample project:

```
<Window x:Class="WpfTests_2.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        ...
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <Grid x:Name="grid1">
        <ScrollViewer>
            <Canvas Background="Green" PreviewMouseWheel="Canvas_PreviewMouseWheel" Width="300" Height="1200"/>
        </ScrollViewer>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Code behind

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void Canvas_PreviewMouseWheel(object sender, MouseWheelEventArgs e)
    {
        e.Handled = true;
    }
}
```

Observed result: when the mouse is over the green area of the canvas, no scrolling on mouse wheel. When the mouse is outside the canvas, the scrollviewer scrolls.

Comment: I tried this but my method only gets called if the ScrollViewer can not scroll any more.

Comment: @horotab edited with my example code. Please try it to verify whether you get the same result for the same code. If you can reproduce my sample, you need to find out, what is different in your actual project. If you can't reproduce, then our systems are somehow very different and I probably cant help you.

Comment: @horotab did you check the example? Is the question still open?

Comment: Yes, i found out the problem is that i have a Devexpress.LayoutControl outside that handles scrolling. Do you maybe know how to prevent it from doing so? I dont want to build the UI with grids :(

Comment: @horotab Sorry, I'm not familiar with DevExpress. If you still expect an answer, you have to update your question with that new information.